# Microsoft Sculpt Ergonomic Desktop issue with usb receiver

Tags: keyboard, mouse, wireless-mouse, wireless-keyboard

I had Microsoft Sculpt Ergonomic Desktop for 1.5 years and the usb dongle stopped receiving data from the keyboard and mouse, I replaced it on warranty.

And now after 5 more years the usb dongle is stopping sometimes, I need to hard press it to one side to make it work, after such pressure for 5 mins it works without pressure.

Did someone had similar issues with the usb receiver for this keyboard/mouse? It is highly unlikely that I'm the only one that had the same problem with two keyboard/mouse sets.

Did anyone tried to fix the issue? Is it enough to open the dongle and see solder some loose parts there?

Or maybe MS will fix it/replace the USB receiver for some amount?

Comment: I can feel your pain. The USB dongle is finicky, no doubt about that. As far as I know the desktop dongle (which contains receivers for both mouse and keyboard) is even better than the keyboard-only dongle, which takes a certain insertion / switching on sequence with delicate timing.

It also woes in combination with some USB hubs. That said, in my opinion there is no better ergonomic keyboard product on the market, so we have to live with it until they create a new iteration.

Answer (score 1):

I found a altenative solution to fix the broken microsoft scultp ergonomic USB dongle.

First you need to buy a generic NRF24LU1 based usb dongle, as show in this link:
https://pt.aliexpress.com/item/1005002721886615.html?spm=a2g0o.order_list.0.0.2140caa4NzV9W7&gatewayAdapt=glo2bra

All you need is remove the original USB dongle IC and replace on new generic USB dongle (i used a SMD repair station).

After this my Microsoft Scultp Ergonomic return to live again \o/